# Does Star Wars d6 (West End Games) have Throw Lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, d6-system

While flipping through the Core Book (2nd ed, Revised & Expanded) the other day, I realized that I did not see any Force power or skill relating to throwing a lightsaber as a ranged attack. I haven't gotten the chance to flip through anything else yet, but I would think it would be in there. I googled the crud out of it, but I did not find any links that clued me into where – or even *if* – WEG' Star Wars has this.

Comment: Bear in mind that this version was written before the prequels, which is where crazy lightsaber hijinx were added to the canon. You might need to look at Force Throw (or the closest in that version) and document a house rule that says how much damage this use of the skill will do.

Comment: WEG d6 star wars!  Woo!  Going home tonight to dig out my book and find you the answer.  :]

Comment: @somori I may misremember RotJ, but didn't Vader throw his lightsaber after Luke in it during their last duel, causing a bit of destruction in the Emperor's throne room and Luke to fall?

Comment: Yes, indeed he did. Yes, Throw is canon, at least for Vader.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like **Telekinesis** is what you're looking for (instead of those droids.) To quote the book (p.151, Core SW d6, 2nd Ed., I'm not sure if it's revised or not, though):

> (...) Object may be moved at 10 meters per round (..) The target must
>   be in sight of the Jedi. Increased difficulty if object isn't moving
>   in simple, straight-line movement: (...)
>   +11 to +25 or more for complex maneuvers, **such as using a levitated lightsaber to attack.** (...) Levitated objects can be used to attack
>   other characters, but this automatically gives the Jedi a Dark Side
>   Point. (...) Such attacks would require an additional *control* roll by
>   the Jedi, which would be the to hit roll against the target's *dodge*.
>   (...)

(**Emphasis** mine.)

Comment: Thank you very much! It was hidden in the difficulty section, not the description. R&E has the equivalent on pp. 147.

Answer (score 1):

LIGHTSABER THROW
Prerequisite: Light- Tier 3 (Specialty), Dark- Tier 3 (Specialty)
Reaction: NO  Focus: YES  Kept up: NO
Time to use: 1 Action  Dark Side: NO
Difficulty:
Sense: Moderate.
Alter: Targets’ Evasion, or Parry.

Modifiers: Must have line of sight. Alter by proximity to target(s).
Description: This power allows a character that is using Lightsaber Combat to hurl his lightsaber toward a target, or targets with unerring accuracy, and power. The character may attack one target for every 3D he has in his Sense skill with this power. Each target rolls to evade or parry the attack separately. 
Upon activating this power the character lets his lightsaber fly out striking the desired target(s) for the lightsaber’s full damage (including bonus damage from Control). Whether the attack hits all, some, or none of the targets, the characters lightsaber returns to his hand at the end of the attack. If one of the targets parries the attack with a lightsaber or melee weapon successfully, the lightsaber returns to the character without hitting any further targets.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify something? Is this homebrewed, or something you're quoting from a rulebook? It's fine either way, but the first implies the answer to the question is "no", and the second implies "yes", which are very different answers, right? :)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.StackExchange!  SevenSidedDie has a good comment on your answer, but I just wanted to encourage you to take a look at our [About] and [Help] to find more information about how the site works.

Comment: Sorry for the delay to a response to your question. Lightsaber throw is a rare rule from one of the Westend

Comment: game put online